# A program that sums two 2x2 matrices done with functions is crashing when I fill in the values

Tags: c++, matrix

I'm very new to this. Was asked to do the following exercise:

> Make a program that would declare two square matrices of 2x2 size and
>   would sum them up. The main program will "load" both matrices with
>   values given by the user (through cin) and will send them to a
>   subprogram that will perform the sum, returning the result. The main
>   program will then output the resulting matrix on screen.

Basically an exercise that would be easily done if not because of the functions part. This is what I've got so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int SIZEX = 2;
const int SIZEY = 2;
typedef float matrix[SIZEX][SIZEY];

void sum_matrix (const matrix p, const matrix q, matrix sum);

int main()
{
    int i,j;
    matrix p, q, sum;

    for(i=0;i<SIZEX;i++)
        for(j=0;j<SIZEY;j++)
        {
            cout<<"Fill in the matrices values" << i << " " << j << endl;
            cin>> p[i][j] >> q[i][j];
        }

    sum_matrix(p, q, sum);

    for(i=0;i<SIZEX;i++)
    {
        cout<<endl;
        for(j=0;j<SIZEY;j++)
            cout<<sum[i][j]<<" ";
    }

    return 0;

}

void sum_matrix (const matrix p, const matrix q, matrix sum)
{
    for(int i=0;i<SIZEX;i++)
        for(int j=0;i<SIZEY;j++)
            sum[i][j]=p[i][j]+q[i][j];
}
```

My compiller throws no errors whatsoever, so I run it. I fill in the values, I press enter to proceed to the calculation and output of the result, and the program crashes. I'm sure this is full of errors, but I just wanted to at least run it to find any, yet it's the first time the cmd crashes for me when doing this.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: You have a typo in your `sum_matrix` here: `for(int j=0;i<SIZEY;j++)`. It loops infinitely (note the `i` instead of `j`). It should be `for(int j=0;j<SIZEY;j++)`. If you use more spaces in your code, it will be easier to see: `for ( int j = 0; i < SIZEY; j++ )`. And spaces don't cost anything. :)

Comment: Such a dumb mistake :( Thanks a lot!! Spent literally hours changing things in this, now it works. Thank you!

Comment: Not dumb. I looked at it several times before I spotted it. It's very hard to see. It's one reason why coding standards recommend spacing.

Comment: That's just a typo. But I will recommend using longer, more descriptive variable names. i and j are easy to mix up and hard to tell apart.